# Proper ExpressJS and NGINX reverse proxy configuration for subdirectory

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a VPS with NGINX installed, it's running a TLD website and I want to run my ExpressJS application from a subdirectory called **nlapp**. E.g. `/var/www/website.com/public_html/nlapp`.

Here's the `app.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/nlapp", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});
```

My NodeJS application runs without errors and it works fine, but it doesn't seem to serve static content this far. I have disabled express static but it still doesn't work.

Here's my configuration for this right now:

```
server {
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    root /var/www/website.com/public_html/;
    index index.html index.php;
    # Modsecurity
    client_max_body_size 100M;



    
    # Logs
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log_website.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log_website.com;

    # Don't allow pages to be rendered in an iframe on external domains.
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    # MIME sniffing prevention
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    # Enable cross-site scripting filter in supported browsers.
    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block";

    # Prevent access to hidden files
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known\/) {
        deny all;
    }

    # Prevent access to certain file extensions
    location ~\.(ini|log|conf)$ {
        deny all;
    }
        
        # Enable WordPress Permananent Links
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        autoindex off;
    }
    
    # Restrict GoAccess
    location /rep_est_status.html {
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    # Cache for 2 days
    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 2d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

        # Deny access to xmlrpc.php
        location = /xmlrpc.php {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                allow 87.71.160.0/19;
                deny all;
        }

    location /nlapp {
        alias /var/www/website.com/public_html/nlapp/public;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

My NodeJS application is running on port 3000, and it worked great on my localhost.
But on this remote NGINX server (that I manage) the static content that is in `/var/www/website.com/public_html/nlapp/public`.
There I have 2 directories: `css` and `images`.

When I load the application from my browser, I go to this URL:
https://www.website.com/nlapp and it launches successfully.
The CSS and images are not loading, I've checked Network tab on dev tools and it seems it's trying to load them from the root directory of the website, e.g. https://www.website.com/css instead of https://www.website.com/nlapp/public/css

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

## What did I try?

I tried using the alias or root directives under the specified location, as seen in the example above.
It didn't amount to anything, still the same.

Also tried googling and searching more and more for a few hours - couldn't arrive at a conclusion.